# Updating document within find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm having issues updating a document from within a find using Mongoose. The issue is only when I attempt to overwrite the document with an object (e.g doc = req.body). I am however able to directly set properties of the original document to a specific string (e.g. doc.name = 'jason borne';).

I've verified that res.body is an object, so I don't see why I'm unable to set it this way.

```
Client.findById(req.params.client_id, function (err, client) {

    if (err)
        return next(new restify.InternalError(err));

    // client.name = 'jason borne';

            client = req.body;

    client.save(function(err) {

        if (err)
            return next(new restify.InternalError(err));

        res.send(client);

    });

});
```

When attempting to set the doc to an object, I receive the error:

TypeError: Object # has no method 'save'

I'm aware that I can do an update with a simple Client.update(...) command, however this method does not allow my schema middleware or validation to run (which is notated in the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)).

Any thoughts? I'm new to Node, and Mongoose.

Comment: it looks like a problem with restify middleware, not mongoose. Are you using bodyParser?

Comment: @soulcheck I'm using the jsonBodyParser as all of our input is a valid JSON payload. It's working great for CREATE, but not so great for PUT. I double checked, and res.body is a valid object, as well as client (the document returned in my findById call).

Comment: are you sure it should be `res.body` and not `req.body`?

Comment: @soulcheck I messed up when creating my question. It should be req.body, but that throws an error TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like underscore's [`extend`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) method to copy the properties of `req.body` into the `client` object instead of just re-pointing `client` to `req.body` as you are now.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
Client.findById(req.params.client_id, function (err, client) {

    if (err)
        return next(new restify.InternalError(err));

    _.extend(client, req.body);
    client.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return next(new restify.InternalError(err));
        res.send(client);
    });
});
```

Comment: _.extend is exactly what I was looking for. Fixes the issue where you have to remove the _id as well. Thanks!

Comment: why didn't I think of that... O_o I was expecting a "fromJSON" method for the models of mongooes since this is quite a common scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms you're now getting are caused by the fact that you're replacing a mogoose model object (with methods like save, find, etc), by a simple json object parsed from your body, which is missing `save`.

Try doing an update instead of find/save.

```
 Client.update({_id: req.params.client_id}, {$set : req.body}, function(err) {...});
```

Or try to merge your `req.body` to the `client` object.